# L value vs R value in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, dereference

I am answering a textbook question from [this textbook](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~louden/pltext/).

I am learning about pointers in C and have come across l-values and r-values. From my understanding:

```
l-values are values that are defined after they are executed (++x)
r-values are values that are not defined after they are executed (x++)
```

It that correct?

The question I wanted to answer (with my attempts):

```
a) Which of the following C expressions are L-Values?
   1.  x + 2 Not a L value
   2.  &x    Is a L value
   3.  *&x   Is a L value
   4.  &x + 2  Not a L value
   5.  *(&x + 2) Is a L value
   6.  &*y  Is a L value

b) Is it possible for a C expression to be a L-value but NOT a R-value? Explain
   I've read that a L value can be a R value but not vice versa. I can't think of an example of something being an L value but not a R value.

c) Is &(&z) ever legal in C? Explain
   Assuming this is not legal since a memory address doesn't have its own memory address?
```

Am I close? Thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged this [tag:c++] ?

Comment: BTW although *value categories* in C and C++ have mostly the same end effect, they get there via very different paths.  There won't be any explanations that apply to both.  A question like this needs to pick one language.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I've deleted the C++ tag, since the OP says he's learning about C.

Comment: (a) R, R, L, R, L, R  (b) No\* (c) No

Comment: I've found the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/misc/lvalue.html) entry to be very useful when explaining lvalues/rvalues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> l-values are values that are defined after they are executed (`++x`)
> r-values are values that are not defined after they are executed (`x++`)

No, that's not correct.

The words "lvalue" and "rvalue" (that's how the C standard spells them) have a long history. The terms come from 'l' for "left" and 'r' for "right", referring to the left and right sides of an assignment.

In some contexts, an expression may be either *evaluated for its lvalue* or *evaluated for its rvalue*. Given those definitions of the terms, an "rvalue" is what you'd normally think of as the value of an expression; evaluating `2+2` yields `4`. Evaluating an expression for its lvalue meant determining what object it refers to. For example, given:

```
int x;
x = 2 + 2;
```

the right side of the assignment, `2 + 2` would be evaluated for its rvalue, yielding `4`, and the left side would be evaluated for its lvalue, which means determining the object to which it refers. (The rvalue of the expression is *not* evaluated; the value previously stored in `x`, if any, is not used.)

The C standard defines them differently. In C, an *lvalue* is not a value; it's a kind of expression. Specifically, quoting the 2011 ISO C standard, section 6.3.2.1:

> An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than void) that
> potentially designates an object; if an lvalue does not designate an
> object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined.

(The word "potentially" was added to cover cases like `*ptr`, where `ptr` is a pointer object; if `ptr == NULL` then `*ptr` doesn't *currently* designate an object, but it's still an lvalue. You can always determine at compile time whether a given expression is an lvalue or not. Earlier editions of the C standard had flawed definitions for *lvalue*.)

So basically an *lvalue* in C is an expression that designates an object. You can think of it as an expression that can appear on the left side of an assignment, though that's not entirely accurate; for example, the name of a `const` object can't be on the LHS of an assignment, but it's still an lvalue. (As you can see, nailing down a precise and consistent definition for *lvalue* can be tricky.)

Neither `x++` nor `++x` is an lvalue in C.

The C standard doesn't use the term *rvalue* beyond mentioning it in a single footnote:

> What is sometimes called "rvalue" is in this International Standard
> described as the "value of an expression".

So, as C defines the terms, an *lvalue* is a kind of expression (something that exists in C source code), but an *rvalue* is the result of evaluating an expression (something that exists during program execution).

(C++ has different rules, and several other classes of lvalue-like things, including *glvalues* and so forth. I won't get into that here.)

Comment: The C standard does not spell rvalue (except in a footnote)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yes, I said that in my answer.