# Convert pair of values to byte[]

Tags: c#

I need a quick way of converting a pair of integers to a byte array. If it were a single value, I could use the following:

```
private static unsafe byte[] ToBytes(int value)
{
    var bytes = new byte[4];
    fixed (byte* pointer = bytes)
    {
        *(int*)pointer = value;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

However I can't quite figure out how you'd do the same for a pair of integers. The following which I tried ***doesn't work*** but should help to show what I'm aiming for

```
private static unsafe byte[] ToBytes(int value1, int value2)
{
    var bytes = new byte[8];
    fixed (byte* pointer = bytes)
    {
        *(int*)pointer = value1;
        *(int*)pointer + 4 = value2;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

(I'm aware I can do the same using BitConverter, but I want to compare the performance of the two)

Comment: Can't you put the int's in a long and then do the unsafe stuff with that long?

Comment: Try `*((int*)pointer + 4) = value2;` or, since the pointer is a pointer to an int, try +1 instead since you want to access "the next int".

Comment: @rene - Thanks. I suspect it'd undo the savings of the micro-optimizations I'm already doing! I'm hoping I can do it without.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - + 1 seems to do trick; I incorrectly assumed it was in bytes

Comment: Put two bytes into an  UInt16 results =  (UInt16)((b[0] <<8) + b[1]); This is faster than BitConverter and gives same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether this will perform better than alternatives I don't know but the correct syntax is like this:

```
*((int)pointer + 1) = value2;
```

This:

```
*(int)pointer + 4 = value2;
```

gives an error because this: `*(int)pointer` is a variable reference and thus your code really looks like this:

```
i + 4 = value2;
```

which is not legal syntax in C#.

Instead encapsulate the addition to the address before dereferencing it into a variable reference (an [lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129586/l-value-vs-r-value-in-c) if you want to google for these things):

```
*((int)pointer + 1)
```

`+4` is also incorrect since the pointer is a "pointer to int", not a "pointer to byte", which means that `+X` is really `+X * sizeof(int)` in terms of byte-level addressing.

Your final method should look like this:

```
private static unsafe byte[] ToBytes(int value1, int value2)
{
    var bytes = new byte[8];
    fixed (byte* pointer = bytes)
    {
        *(int*)pointer = value1;
        *((int*)pointer + 1) = value2;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. It seems to do the trick. (will mark as answer when I can)